# How can I save specific comment meta data when a comment is posted using Wpdiscuz

Tags: wordpress, comments, metadata

I am trying to save comment meta data when a comment is posted so I know which image the commented was posted on. Here is that code I am trying to use. Whenever I use this code it just saves the the comment meta_value as "NULL".
It seems I'm having trouble getting the $imageID value to the "save_comment_meta_data" function.

webpage code:

`$imageID = 1;`

functions.php:

````
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
    $html = "";
    global $imageID;
    if (file_exists(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php")) {
        ob_start();
        include_once ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php";
        $html = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode("wpdiscuz_comments", "my_wpdiscuz_shortcode");


function add_custom_comment_fields() {
    global $imageID;
    if ( isset( $imageID ) ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="' . esc_attr( $imageID ) . '">';
    }
}
add_action( 'wpdiscuz_form_bottom', 'add_custom_comment_fields' );



function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['image_id'] ) ) {
        $meta_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['image_id'] );
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'image_id', $meta_value, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the fix.

I changed `wpdiscuz_form_bottom` to `comment_form`. The comment meta data is now updating properly. I hope this helps someone else in the future.